# How to get column name depends on other table rows data. dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, telerik-reporting

As The Question says that I'm trying to get column name depends on other table rows data, and there is no relationship between each other. I'm using Telerik reporting toll and I want to write a query to get this data

Example...

**table A**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|id| |name|           | 2010| | 2011| | 2012| | 2013| ...| 2060|

----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   stream1            122    221      123   111
2   stream2            134    222      234   222
3   stream3            155    243      234   333
4   stream4            123    144      345   444
...................................................................
```

**table B**

```
--------------------
|yearsid| |years|          
--------------------
1        2010           
2        2011            
3        2020            
4        2050            
....................
```

**what I looking for**

```
---------------------------------------------------
 |name|           | 2010| | 2011| | 2020| | 2050 | 

----------------------------------------------------
 stream1            122    221      21   170
 stream2            134    222      25   256
 stream3            155    243      50   568
 stream4            123    144      63   430
..................................................
```

I want to get the select column name from table A depends on the years' name in table B
and those data are not static.

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL so if Telerik doesn't support this directly does it at least support calling a stored procedure? How about the version of SQL Server you're using?

Comment: it's SQL server 2019, I couldn't understand how dynamic SQL will help me I didn't try it and yes it supports stored procedures.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL because SQL Server can't reference a column from data in a table... it would be like `DECLARE @variable sysname = N'column_name'; SELECT @variable FROM dbo.table;` - that just doesn't work. Stored procedures would only be relevant if your reporting tool doesn't allow you to use certain T-SQL structures (a lot of tools are limited in what they support/allow, and not everyone here is going to know your tool).

Comment: fine, I understand now thanks Aaron so much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Telerik can run dynamic SQL, this will generate a list of the column names found in `TableB`, then add those into a query against `TableA`. As added protection from SQL injection, it verifies that the columns actually exist in `TableA`:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT id';

SELECT @sql += ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
  ON c.name = CONVERT(sysname, years)
  WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TableA');;
  
SET @sql += N' FROM dbo.TableA';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6923f19f8a45aec0c8a3ce1d9b7532d5)

That will work on all supported versions. A slightly different 2017+ version uses `STRING_AGG()`, which is just a little bit cleaner:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT id,' 
    + STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ',') 
    + N' FROM dbo.TableA'
  FROM sys.columns AS c
  INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
  ON c.name = CONVERT(sysname, years)
  WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TableA');
  
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dec502a0124cb8da112ff08ee6959ac)

Comment: thank so much, but I have another question what if I want to add where condition when I select the name from table A?

Comment: @Reem can you be more specific? It's great when you include your whole problem in the question, so we can solve it once, instead of once for every time you add a new requirement. :) (Also, this is quite an anti-pattern, storing data in columns named for the data they contain - much better to store that data in a row, then it is much easier to query.)

Comment: @Reem Examples: [single int param](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a984f0812a845a80cf3c3a9783990754), [single string param](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4a0ecf1258c92fbb608d1d08af854fc), [multiple int params](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=946b1fc23c63ad5939deadb5a75ebb65).